# Is it possible to set auto-increment-increment by 10 for only one table?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is it possible to add auto-increment-increment by 10 for only one table in mysql?

I have a testing db that has a lot of tables that do not abide by the auto-increment-increment of 10.  I won't want to mess up my testing rig.

The production server has auto-increment-increment of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MySQL documentation, you can't set custom auto-increment value for a specific table.

> It is not possible to restrict the effects of these two variables to a single table; these variables control the behavior of all AUTO_INCREMENT columns in all tables on the MySQL server.

However, this value has both global and session level effect. You may set it for session level and can perform required tests. And the changes will not persist after restarting your database server.

**Reference:**
[auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html)

Comment: Looks like docker will need to save the day when testing this setup.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can set auto-increment in Microsoft SQL but I don't think MySQL allows such, they auto-increment for you. You can only set your starting value of the auto-increment but not the common difference.

You should use Microsoft SQL if you really need auto-increment by. This feature is aided by IDENTITY(2,5) where the first value is 2 and the subsequent values increase by 5 in this example.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

The link is for Microsoft SQL